# Java: Mouse position in game

Tags: java, location, mouse, point

I am using the `MouseInfo` class to get the mouse position like this way:

`public static void main (String[] args){
    Point mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

}`

It works perfectly on any desktop application, but since inside a game the mouse ubication point is the same everytime, this gets completely useless.

I supposed that the best alternative is to **track the mouse movement** instead of the ubication of the cursor, but i dont have any idea about how to do it.

Could you tell me some way to do this or a better idea for this purpose? Does this depends of the mouse (*specific driver it uses or brand*)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Comment: Whatever framework you are using for your application, it should have some API to allow you to get position of mouse pointer. For example, in case of Java Swing, you have `MouseMotionListener` that you can add to `JPanel` or `JFrame`.

Comment: You need to call `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` every time you want the location.  `mousePosition` isn't updated once you've got it.

Comment: Im doing it. For each click the Point that stores the cursor location is updated

Comment: And `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` returns the same point every time?

Comment: Yes, in game. Because the game where im trying to do this (CSGO) holds the mouse location at the same position. I think most of the shooters works in this way

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?  If the mouse doesn't move, you will always get the same position regardless of what method you use.

Comment: The problem is exactly that, the mouse is in movement, but at the end it gets centered again. The way i tested this was binding to right button on my mouse `System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation())` while moving the mouse in game and i was getting the same X and Y each time.